# Wordpress check if user is logged in from non wordpress page

Tags: categories, login

I am using wordpress and I normally use:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()){
   //something here
}
```

to detect if the wordpress user is logged in or now.

My problem is that I need to detect if the user is logged in to wordpress from a non-wordpress page.

My page is in the same directory as the other wordpress pages but is not page of wordpress.

How can I detect this from my page?

Answer (score 5):

Simply place

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
include 'wp-load.php';
```

on to of your template files (before *everything else*). This loads the whole WP core.

Answer (score -2):

this is untested by me, but please have a look at this article: [Integrating Wordpress into an Existing Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aJalenack/Integrating_Wordpress_into_an_Existing_Site)

In essence I believe that if you use:

```
<?php require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');?>
```

..at the top of you (php) page you should be able to take advantage of the is_user_logged_in() function.

Comment: Hi, I'm new to Stack Exchange in general, so is there a way I can see why a post is voted down? Presumably this didnt work, or did I not include enough info?

Comment: Normally the downvoter _should_ leave a reply, but they're not forced to.